# Importing skeletal animation from vertex coordinates in maya

Tags: animation, skeletal-animation, maya, motion

I have files of different frames of an animation which have the vertex co-ordinates of a human skeleton in 3D space. I want to import the animation from these keyframes into maya to perform motion retargeting. Please help me get some direction in this.

Also is there any other way to retarget motion from one skeleton to other(different size) other than in maya?

Comment: obj doesn't support animation, so do you mean you have a freeze-frame of the skeleton in dozens of different files?

Comment: I don't think .obj supports skeletons either, unless the standard suddenly updated in the last 2 days.

Comment: unless you make it an extension of sorts that adds the skeleton data

Comment: I am a newbie and as a part of my project I have to do motion retargeting from one skeleton to other. I have the vertex coordinates of the skeletal joints in each frame. I want to import it into maya and perform retargeting to other skeleton. I thought it could be done by obj but doesnt look so. Please guide me through this.

Comment: @jhocking Yes, each file represents the skeletal coordinates in a frame. I want to import this animation of skeletion (without mesh) to Maya to retarget motion. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest looking into Collada. (.dae) It uses XML. So you can open it in any text editor. However, you need to download a plugin for maya to import and export these files. You can download those here http://sourceforge.net/projects/colladamaya/files/ 
Also, as for the motion retargeting, look into this http://gameware.autodesk.com/humanik/features